# Show mousepoint while doing drag and drop in WPF

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, mouse-position

I am using [Lesters DragAndDropManager](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2006/12/08/drag-drop-library.aspx) 
to get the drag and drop function in my application and i really like the way it's implemented, but I have one small problem and that is that I want to show the mouse cordination during the drag in my statusbar, so how do I send the mouseposition from the DropManager to my xaml code.

I have tried to add a dependencyproperty in the manager that I can bind to in the xaml-code.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MousePointProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MousePoint", typeof(Point), typeof(DragDropBehavior),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Point)));
    public static void SetMousePoint(DependencyObject depObj, bool isSet)
    {
        depObj.SetValue(MousePointProperty, isSet);
    }
    public static IDragSourceAdvisor GetMousePoint(DependencyObject depObj)
    {
        return depObj.GetValue(MousePointProperty) as IDragSourceAdvisor;
    }
```

And in the Xaml I bind to it like this.

```
    <StatusBar>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding local:DragDropBehavior.MousePoint.X}"/>
    </StatusBar>
```

But how do I set the mousecordintation to my dependecyproperty in the manager?

```
    private static void DropTarget_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (UpdateEffects(sender, e) == false) return;
        //-- Update position of the preview Adorner
        Point position = GetMousePosition(sender as UIElement);

        //-- Here I Want to do this, but that not posible because the SetMousePoint takes a dependencyObject and not my value.
        //-- SetMousePoint(position);

        _draggedUIElementAdorner.Left = position.X - _offsetPoint.X;
        _draggedUIElementAdorner.Top = position.Y - _offsetPoint.Y;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I think I am wrong here, but I have get stuck on how to get the mousecordination to the xaml-code by binding to the DragAndDropManager.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly. You cannot bind to attached property, in a way you want, because you have to know an object where it's attached.

How to do this? I see three options (but there are many more).

1. Whenever you are dragging use global mouse events listener ([Mouse.MouseMoveEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mousemoveevent(VS.85).aspx)) in the custom status bar class.
2. Expose static event from `DragAndDropManager`, subscribe to it in the custom status bar class. Whenever drag occurs, fire event from `DragAndDropManager`. But be careful with static events. It's very easy to introduce a memory leak...
3. Convert `DragAndDropManager` into singleton. Implement INotifyValueChanged in it, create instance property `MousePoint`, for say. Bind to it from statusbar:

   Text="{Binding MousePoint.X, Source={x:Static local:DragDropBehavior.Instance}}"

Whenever drag occurs, update instance property, and raise property changed event.

Hope this helps,

Cheers, Anvaka